# How to assign files to different html element using dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

In my html page  pFile element is there

```
<input type="file" name="pFile" id="primaryFile-20" size="35" maxlength="250" value="">
```

How to assign file to that ID after drag and drop ?

I can't edit the html page . Only thing I can do is create javascript file to over write it

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        autoProcessQueue : false,
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drop file here and use checkin button for upload",
    url: "/cs/idcplg?",
    init : function() {

   myDropzone = this;

             this.on("dragend",function(event) {

document.getElementsByName("pFile).files=myDropzone.files;   

}



}


}
```

This is approaching not working

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I mean what is the goal?

Comment: I want to use drag and drop feature . default feature with URL is not possible in my case .  I want to assign files to different html element

Comment: Why is default URL behaviour not possible? Why do you want to assign files to different html elements? It is still unclear what you are trying to do, and why the normal Dropzone won't work for you.